# bash: including both \n and double-quotes in a string variable

Tags: string, bash, newline, double-quotes

I have a string that I want to enclose in double quotes and place a newline character before it. This is how I want the output to look:

```
 
"my string"
```

Here's what I thought would work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

input='my string'
output=$"[\n\"$input\" ]"
```

But instead, I get this:

```
 \n"my string"
```

How can I persuade bash to convert `\n` to a newline character?

Comment: Use: `output=$'\n'\"$input\"`

Comment: (or) use `printf` as `printf -v outputString '\n\"my string\"'` and do `printf '%s' "$outputString"`

Comment: This worked for me:  `output="\n\"$input\""`